# Not uploading multiple files

Tags: php, html

I borrowed this code from another StackOverflow question, yet for some reason I cannot get it to work. When testing it is not even passing the files. My error testing shows

> total: 0

So it fails right there. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
session_start();
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
echo "total: " . $total;
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    echo $tempFilePath . "<br>";
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "/images/prod/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        echo $newFilePath . "<br>";
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            echo $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        }
    }
}

<form action="addpics.php" method="get" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data>
<input type="file" name="imgs[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" value=" - ADD - ">
</form>
```

Expect the files to upload to the /images/prod folder
and echo the array of file names

Comment: So what is the contents of $_FILES?

Comment: You are missing a `"` after `"multipart/form-data>`

Comment: `$_FILES['upload']` is empty because your field name is "imgs[]" - Try changing the input to be `<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple>`

Comment: Made the suggested changes and still getting the same result.

Comment: You didn't do what I asked for.

Comment: the content of $_FILES are images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your method, enctype & field name is wrong. As others have mentioned you are missing the quote on enctype.

You are trying to get the upload field from your form but the form doesn't have this field, so you need to update file input and rename it to `upload[]`

Also you are trying to submit the form via a GET request which wont pass the data across.

This code should fix the issue (I've changed it so it posts to itself rather than your `addpics.php` file)

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
session_start();
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

echo "total: " . $total;
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    echo $tempFilePath . "<br>";
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "/images/prod/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        echo $newFilePath . "<br>";
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            echo $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        }
    }
}}
?>
<form method="post" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" value=" - ADD - ">
</form>
```

Comment: Using your code I get this. The only thing I did not change was having the form post to the addpics.php dude to the other things I have working on the page the form is on. Would this have caused these errors?
---
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/prod/giphy.gif): failed to open stream: No 
such file or directory in /home/pndprodu/nerdsforhire.pnd- 
productions.com/addpics.php on line 13
---
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpEUN75n' to 
'/images/prod/giphy.gif' in /home/pndprodu/nerdsforhire.pnd- 
productions.com/addpics.php on line 13

Comment: I have checked all the permissions are 777 for the _prod_ folder.

Comment: I would assume its looking for the `/images/` folder in the root of your system, if you get rid of the first `/` it might produce a different error or fix the issue - not sure

Comment: that is what I did! Thank you again for your assistance... Now I am working on getting the multiple files -imploded- into an array to be put into the one col/row so the other script can explode it... I do appreciate the assistance and getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the inverted comma of enctype. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`